# What is the simplest approach to deploying a custom datalab vm on Google Cloud Compute Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, dockerfile, google-cloud-datalab

[This wiki](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/datalab/wiki/Getting-Started) was very helpful in providing a lot of detail about the process of deploying a custom datalab vm in the GCE.

In particular, the ['Releasing A Build' page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datalab/wiki/Releasing-a-Build) documented the following location for the most current Datalab Docker container:  gcr.io/cloud_datalab/datalab:latest.

Ultimately, for production, I'll conform to all of the release steps, particularly testing locally. Since I'm working in a Sandbox, however, I'd like to believe that I can streamline the process.  That is, I'd like to simply clone the datalab:latest, make my changes, save it to my Git repo, and then use the Deployer App to create a new version (with an appropriate name) and set the `container =` deployer URL parameter to my customized image (i.e. Docker file).

My questions are:

1. Does this seem like a correct and reasonable approach ?
2. Is [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datalab/blob/master/containers/datalab/Dockerfile.in) the datalab:latest Docker file?
3. Is the dockerfile.in what I need to clone and then make changes to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Yes.
3. No, you should clone all project, because Dockerfile.in has references to projects. For example config/ipython.py. You can see this in the [116 line](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datalab/blob/master/containers/datalab/Dockerfile.in#L116). (# Add build artifacts)